# Rounded Image on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

[image]

Guys, I want to crop my image following the red circle shape, removing what is outside the circle. I wasn't able to achieve this using my Crystal Reports XI Release 2. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to superimpose (cover) the parts you don't want to see with white images. I don't think Crystal supports transparent images, so you might need a top and bottom white images.

Another option is to execute an image crop on the fly via a UFL. At least one of the UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/crystal-reports-ufl) already supports rectangular image crop on the fly. It is possible to implement the same with a circular image crop.

Comment: I have created a circle with border only on Gimp, then I imported to Crystal using Microsoft Word. This way, I was able to achieve what I was desiring.